# Include multiple CloudFormation templates in CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I have two separate Cloudformation templates, A and B, where B depends on the output of A (e.g., B uses the instance role from A, A creates the instance role).

How do I achieve this in CDK?

```
const tmpl = new cfninc.CfnInclude(this, `included-template`, {
    templateFile: path.join('cfn-templates', 'HI.yaml'),
  });
```

And use the output from `tmpl.Outputs['InstanceRoleId']`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use resources directly, no need to even create outputs:

```js
const tmpl = tmpl.getResource('InstanceRole') as iam.CfnRole;
```